# Two users, full access to same folder

Tags: linux, permissions, directory

I have a laptop running Arch Linux, and an owncloud-client. I have an owncloud server on my local network. When outside of my local network, I must use a dyn dns URL to get to my server. When on the local network, any queries to that same URL (Or just the IP address of the network as it appears on the WAN) are terminated (this is a network thing, not my computers). So.

I want to have 2 owncloud clients. One for when I'm away, and one when I'm at home. But I want them to sync to the same folder. And I don't want them to require a breach of data security (aka opening my home folder to anybody) to do it.

Can I? How?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the dyndns name to /etc/hosts when you're at home so that it resolves to your local IP, and use some scripts easily add/remove it.

Or install a DNS server on your local network that would resolve the dyndns name to your local IP.